# ¿Cómo se puede crear una tabla automatica que recoja los datos de un formulario html?

Tags: php, mysql, formularios, tabla-dinámica

Buenas alguien sabria hacer un formulario que se enviase a una página y que dentro de esa pagina se crease una tabla a medida que se vaya necesitando¿¿
A eso me refiero que la gente desde el form de login (ya creado) enviasen los datos a una pagina llamada index.php y que es esta pagina se organizara en una tabla automatica.

Necesito ayuda ya que no se de php o Mysql y me es bastante urgente

**FORMULARIO LOGIN**

```
<div class="w3-col m6">
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
        <div class="w3-half">
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Usuario reportado" required name="Usuario">             
        </div>
        <div class="w3-half">
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Hora" required name="Hora">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
        <div class="w3-half">                   
            <select class="w3-button w3-"name="sancion" id="sancion">
                <option value="flood">FLOOD </option>
                <option value="spam">SPAM </option>
                <option value="tpakill">TPAKILL </option>
                <option value="hack">HACK </option>
                <option value="abuso_bug">ABUSO DE BUGS  </option>
                <option value="flood">FLOOD </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-half">
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="" required name="Name" placeholder="Descripccion">
        </div>
        <br> 
        <!-- boton enviar-->
        <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-section w3-right" type="submit">ENVIAR</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Index.php**
Es el lugar a donde se accede con el login y donde se encuentra la tabla

```
    <table class="w3-table-all w3-hoverable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="w3-light-grey">
        <th>Usuario Reportado</th>
        <th>Hora</th>
        <th>Motivo</th>
        <th>Descripción</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Pepito</td>
      <td>13:00</td>
      <td>Flood</td>
      <td>subefotos//</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Tinita521</td>
      <td>18:00</td>
      <td>Spam</td>
      <td>inmagur//</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>CerkusNade</td>
      <td>1:00</td>
      <td>Ser demasiado buena :v</td>
      <td>las tiene un staff</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**Base de datos**
Nombre de la tabla: Sanciones
Campos:

1. Usuario
2. Hora
3. Motivo
4. Descripción
5. Procesado (este es un campo que ya tengo hecho que simplemente es de un color rojo exepto que se clickee en el que se vuelve rojo)

**Modificado; nuevos datos**
PD: la class es por el css si no se pudiese hacer decidmelo gracias
Gracias

ATT: Brouse_13

Comment: Claro que se puede hacer, pero antes te recomiendo que pases por la sección de [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que mejores tu pregunta, y cuéntanos que haz intentado en base a lo que solicitas, podrías ingresar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: no te entendi, la pregunta se entiende; no he intentado nada ya que no se php o sql por eso pedi ayuda                                                              PD: sabrias hacerlo¿? si es asi me podrias ayudar¿?

Comment: Lo que preguntas es muy extenso, necesitas crear una base de datos lo primero. Necesitarás aprender lo básico de php

Comment: la base de datos la tengo creada con los campos que necesitare alamcenar, tmb tengo creado la sentencia de sql que me conecta a la base de datos

Comment: Mi respuesta dice que quieres que te ayudemos, y queremos ayudarte, pero no nos dices mucho, por ejemplo la estructura de tu base de datos, tu código de login de php, el código de tu index.php, solo nos muestras tu html de login y pues eso no nos dice nada.

Comment: Ya modifique la informacion que me dijiste asi estaria bien¿?